# testing Razor views in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, razor-2

We have a quite large web-application in ASP.Net MVC, which has a good amount of views.  Starting the application takes quite some time, due to application initialisation logic, etc.

Is there any way to 'test' a view, without actually having to 'start' the web-application in Visual Studio?  The idea is to be able to mock the Model and pass in a custom model, and check that the view renders correctly.  The view is also using Master Layouts, so that would be something that needs to be considered.  We are wasting a lot of time going through the start/stop process of the application, and would like to see if there is actually any other way forward.

Comment: I don't know would it help but you could turn on views compilation.

Comment: @DenysDenysenko Are you referring to the boolean in the .csproj?  Because if so, that drastically slows down the start/stop process, as build time increases greatly.  I am looking into ways how I can make the visual 'testing' process faster.

Comment: Yes I meant that. If this isn't suitable for you then I'd suggest you writing unit tests for the view datas and make your views as simple as possible.

Comment: can't you create mockups, if you only want to test the html??

Comment: I do not want to do 'unit-testing' on the views, but manually inspecting visually to make sure they match the designs.  The problem with creating and trying to load just the HTML only on it's own is that it uses layouts etc, which would be problematic to 'mock'.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. We use Selenium WebDriver with Specflow to test the best part of our site. We do this as part of a full regression test suite that we can run at the flick of a button with our CI server (Team City).

You may also want to consider using PhantomJS, http://phantomjs.org/. This will give you faster results as there's not browser involved.

Other than that, I don't know of anything built in to/on top of MVC specifically that can aid you.

If you've a large volume start by breaking your site down and workout what the most important parts are. I would look to focus on those first to validate your testing process.